# How does "wegpissen" translate?

Tags: translation, slang

Sometimes I read the following expressions:

> Dieses Video ist zum Wegpissen.
>
> Ich könnt mich jedesmal wegpissen!

Obviously *"to piss off"* does not fit the context. Where does this expression come from, and how would it be translated?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The expression `sich wegpissen` has probably evolved from

> Sich wegschmeißen vor lachen

(which is not vulgar) and

> Sich bepissen vor lachen.

As has already been said by others, the latter one obviously comes from the imagination that you have to lough so hard you can't hold back your urine anymore. Like in your example you can say

> Dieses Video ist zum Wegschmeißen.

Which is a quite common expression and will be understood without mentioning the verb `lachen`. I think this is when the two expressions above have been mixed up to `zum Wegpissen`.
According to Google, the expression `zum Bepissen` is much more common than `zum Wegpissen` (425,000 vs 15,400) which leads me to the conclusion that it has arisen as assumed above.

Answer (score 13):

An English translation could be

> The video is so funny you'll pee your pants.
>   I just peed myself – it's so funny.

Both German and English phrases are obviously colloquial and vulgar expressions.

Comment: Is it only used as "zum wegpissen", or can you also say that "ich habe weggepisst"?

Comment: you'll have to add a reflexive pronoun then: "Ich habe mich weggepisst."

Comment: In British English, I think most people would understand _piss funny_ as a direct translation.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate this with `to be convulsed with laughter`.
It probably comes from wetting your pants while laughing so hard, as `pissen` means to piss.

Answer (score 0):

I would translate it as "piss away."

That could have a literal connotation of "urination." But it might also mean "to waste," as to "piss away" (waste) time.

In this regard, the German synonym I might use is "wegwerfen."